# How can I find any repeated duplication in my file

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

How can I find if my file has any repeated duplication. ?

Many of my vi files have large number of molecular co-ordinates, and sometimes, the software I use duplicates molecular co-ordinates on top of the first one, which goes unnoticed and only when I start using the molecule in simulations, that I get to know that this file had a repeated co-rodinates.

Using general grep, i need to  test for every line , and see if a pattern is found.

Instead, is there a better approach ?

Ex:

```
C          8.72073       15.19207       10.44503

C          9.57223       14.02835       10.59743

C         10.54225       13.88199        9.86998
```

repeats in the file

Comment: those duplications stretch over the while line, or can be substrings of any line?

Comment: those duplications stretch over the line. For Ex.
C 1.23 3.45 4.56
H  4.56 3.45 4.56
might repeat

Comment: Give us a few lines from the file, preferably ones with duplicates..

Comment: @Korem : I have added it to the question now..

Comment: @mpapec desired output :  tells me which line is repeated,along with its line number.

Comment: Are last two lines duplicates of the first one?

Comment: @mpapec no, the last two lines are not duplicates, I am searhcing for exactly duplicated lines, and trying to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort` and `uniq` plus `sed` to clean the output:

Example:

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc\na\nb'
a
b
c
a
b

echo -e 'a\nb\nc\na\nb' | sort | uniq -c
      2 a
      2 b
      1 c

echo -e 'a\nb\nc\na\nb' | sort | uniq -c | sed -re '/^\s+1\s+/d; s/^\s+[0-9]+\s+//g'
a
b
```